# Ordenar tabla de codigos con formato de serie (-xx)

Tags: vb.net, tablas

Estoy realizando una aplicación que se maneja con códigos, muchas veces se deben consultar estos datos ordenadas por el numero de serie 
Ejemplo:

```
Codigo-1
Codigo-2
Codigo-3
Codigo-4
```

Hasta aquí todo bien, pero cuando manejo muchos datos pasa esto

```
Codigo-1
Codigo-10
Codigo-11
Codigo-12
Codigo-2
Codigo-3
Codigo-4
Codigo-5
Codigo-6
Codigo-7
Codigo-8
Codigo-9
```

A que se debe?

Si sirve de utilidad la forma que uso para ver estos datos es a travez de un datagridview que se alimenta de una base de datos SQL Server.

```
Dim conndgt As New SqlConnection
    conndgt.ConnectionString = conexion
    rutadgt = New SqlCommand("Select * FROM OrdenesDeCompraExion WHERE NumeroDeOrden='" + ndo.Text + "'", conndgt)
    Dim adapterdgt As New SqlDataAdapter(rutadgt)
    Dim tabledgt As New DataTable()
    conndgt.Open()
    Try
        adapterdgt.Fill(tabledgt)

        If tabledgt.Rows.Count() > 0 Then
            DataGridView1.DataSource = tabledgt
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing
        MsgBox("Revise el numero de orden de compra." + vbNewLine + ex.Message)

    End Try
```

Recuerdo que en Excel el problema es el mismo, se agrupan de la misma manera.

Comment: Entiendo que estás asignando un `DataTable` al `DataGridView`? Podrías editar tu pregunta y añadir algo de código relevante?

Comment: Echo!. Exacto, mediante una datatable hago la carga de datos al datagridview.

Comment: Echa un vistazo a mi respuesta a ver si lo entiendes y te sirve.

Comment: Se entendió a la perfección, gracias Pikoh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La cuestión es que al ser un `string`, el orden se hace como tal. Y, tomado como un `string`,  `"10"<"2"`.

Hay muchas soluciones al problema, dependiendo de cada caso en concreto. Una que puedes utilizar es la siguiente, haciendo uso de Linq.

Asumiendo que el patrón es siempre `texto-numero`, lo que debes hacer es ordenar únicamente por la parte númerica, previa conversión a `Int`.

Te pongo un ejemplo usando una `List`. Si es otro tipo de estructura la forma sería muy similar:

```
Dim codigos As List(Of String) = New List(Of String) From {
    "Codigo-1",
    "Codigo-2",
    "Codigo-3",
    "Codigo-10",
    "Codigo-11",
    "Codigo-12",
    "Codigo-4",
    "Codigo-5",
    "Codigo-6",
    "Codigo-7",
    "Codigo-8",
    "Codigo-9"
}
Dim ordenado = codigos.OrderBy(Function(x) Integer.Parse(x.Split("-"c)(1)))
```

La "magia" está en la última función. Como ves, lo primero que se aplica a cada elemento es `Split("-"c)`, lo que lo divide en `Codigo` por un lado, y el numero por otro. El numero se encuentra en la posición 1 del array devuelto por `Split`, y lo que hacemos es aplicarle `Integer.Parse` para convertirlo en un entero. Este es el resultado que usa `OrderBy` para devolver la colección correctamente ordenada usando solo la parte numérica.

Como estás usando un `DataTable`, debes usar `AsEnumerable` para poder aplicarle linq. Sería algo asi:

```
If tabledgt.Rows.Count() > 0 Then
    Dim ordenado = tabledgt.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(Function(x) Integer.Parse(x.Split("-"c)(1)))
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ordenado
End If
```